# Error importando: Operation has completed with errors

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, mysql-workbench

Estoy intentando hacer forward engineer de un modelo para pasarlo a SQL y me lanza un error de sintaxis , el mensaje dice que se completo con errores, el error como dije es de sintaxis, pero si el mismo workbench hace el script, ¿por qué lo saca con errores?

Éste es el error:

```
Executing SQL script in server

ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
syntax to use near '   CONSTRAINT fk_saldo_usuario
    FOREIGN KEY (usuario_cod_usuario)
    REF' at line 10 SQL Code:
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        -- Table wallet.saldo
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS wallet.saldo (
          cod_saldo INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          saldo_meta VARCHAR(45) NULL,
          saldo_actual VARCHAR(45) NULL,
          usuario_cod_usuario INT NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (cod_saldo),
          INDEX fk_saldo_usuario_idx(usuario_cod_usuario ASC) VISIBLE,
          CONSTRAINT fk_saldo_usuari
            FOREIGN KEY (usuario_cod_usuario)
            REFERENCES wallet.usuario (cod_usuario)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
        ENGINE = InnoDB

SQL script execution finished: statements: 6 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch
```

Antes no me pasaba esto, pero últimamente me ha pasado.

Comment: Por lo que veo tienes el ENGINE InnoDB.
Estás seguro que tu MariaDB server tiene ese mismo engine configurado por defecto??

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/choosing-the-right-storage-engine/

Comment: hola alejandro, si el MariaDB tiene ese server, me consta porque al momento de hacer anteriores bases de datos no me saltaba el error, pero si fuera por el ENGINE InnoDb, cúal sería la solución, aunque no creo por que MySQL siempre trabaja con el InnoDb

Comment: ¿Qué versión tienes de MariaDB?

Comment: generalmente MySql cuando hace el respaldo a lo ultimo coloca los Foreign Keys para asegurarse que la tabla exista

Comment: oscar, tengo la versión 10.1.34

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que la nomenclatura del index, es diferente.

el error da en la linea 10,

He probado en SQLFiddle, y así parece que quita el error:

A mí me reportaba ahí:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'VISIBLE'

Así que he quitado el VISIBLE, ya que por defecto los índices serán visibles, y parece haber avanzado.

¿Puedes probarlo?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS wallet.saldo (
          cod_saldo INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          saldo_meta VARCHAR(45) NULL,
          saldo_actual VARCHAR(45) NULL,
          usuario_cod_usuario INT NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (cod_saldo),
          INDEX `fk_saldo_usuario_idx` (usuario_cod_usuario ASC) ,
          CONSTRAINT fk_saldo_usuario_idx
            REFERENCES wallet.usuario (cod_usuario)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
        ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Comment: Alejandro, si me funcionó, quité los VISIBLE y funcionó, muchas gracias  de verdad

Comment: @EstebanCalle entonces, puedes aceptar la respuesta como correcta??? Me alegro que te haya funcionado!!

Answer (score 2):

Los [índices invisibles](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/invisible-indexes.html) fueron agregados a MySQL 8.0, pero tu versión de MariaDB (10.1.34) es equivalente en funcionalidad a MySQL 5.7, por lo que el modificador de visibilidad de un índice (`VISIBLE` e `INVISIBLE`) no están disponibles en tu servidor MySQL.

Debes exportar la estructura indicando compatibilidad con MySQL 5.7 o bien eliminar manualmente dichos modificadores tanto en la definición como en las relaciones.

Además, los modificadores `ASC` o `DESC` en ellos no cambian realmente el orden hasta la versión 8.0 (aunque están disponibles para usarlos desde la versión 5.7), así que también podrías omitirlos:

Tu consulta, sin los modificadores que pueden darte problemas, debería ser:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS wallet.saldo (
  cod_saldo INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  saldo_meta VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  saldo_actual VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  usuario_cod_usuario INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (cod_saldo),
  INDEX fk_saldo_usuario_idx(usuario_cod_usuario),
  CONSTRAINT fk_saldo_usuari
    FOREIGN KEY (usuario_cod_usuario)
    REFERENCES wallet.usuario (cod_usuario)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```